# React Native - What's the point of leaving trailing comma everywhere?

Tags: javascript, conventions, jshint, react-native

While working with React Native I noticed some strange convention by its' contributors and in examples - **to leave trailing comma everywhere**, as an example:

- http://url.brentvatne.ca/1hCiI
- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/Movies/MoviesApp.js#L20-L24

What's the point?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Then when you perform `diff` only one line is changed.

If you don't do that - 2 lines will be marked as changed.

Technically you can put comma in the beginning of the line and change your style but it's (WARNING: hardly opinionated) ugly.

If I remember correctly, it's valid to specify it when you destructure JS objects, but it's invalid to do so when you use it as a JS object literal (please correct me if I'm wrong).

So this:

```
var { foo, } = obj;
```

is a valid ES6 code.

And this:

```
var o = { foo: 42, };
```

is not a valid JS code.

Comment: Not sure about the ES6 spec but trailing commas crashes IE but works everywhere else (not sure up to which version of IE since I don't use IE). So the **traditional** advice was to always avoid trailing commas in js - lest you get burned when your users use a browser you don't use (IE)

Answer (score 4):

First, if you have a snippet like this:

```
{
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b'
}
```

and add a line to it, you have to remember to add a comma after `'b'`, otherwise you'll get a syntax error with this:

```
{
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b'
    c: 'c'
}
```

If you put a comma everywhere, you don't even have to think about that.
The same goes for swapping and removing lines.

Second, if you're using a version management system such a git or svn and add a line, you have to append a comma to the previous line, thus two lines have changed instead of one.

And third, it looks more consistent, especially when all keys and values have the same length:

```
{
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b',
    c: 'c',
    d: 'd',
    e: 'e',
    f: 'f'  // <-- Aren't you bothered by this?
}
```

Comment: You could say the same about memory-safety in programming, but the vast amount of memory leaks across various applications show that people actually tend to forget things.

Comment: I said that because - syntactically incorrect code just will not run. While a code with a memory leak will run fine. So not sure what your analogy is about. So you technically cannot forget to add a comma here.

Comment: You're right, forget my analogy, you're just less likely to run into an error.

Answer (score 1):

You could end up with these kind of situations, simple but very hard to debug and find:

```
[
    -7,
    -2,
    -1,
    -3   // <-- this simple skip would cause a -7 here (-3 - 4) with no errors
    -4,
    -2,
    -9
];
```

So yes, I would prefer to adopt the trailing comma in every line.